# passing struct to pthread as an argument

Tags: c, multithreading, struct, pthreads

Ok I am trying to pass pair of numbers through `struct` to `pthread_create` function in `pthread`. But the numbers i am passing and numbers i am getting when the function is called are different and random

Here is the `struct`

```
struct Pairs {
    long i,j;
};
```

And inside main

```
void main()
{
    long thread_cmp_count = (long)n*(n-1)/2;
    long t,index = 0;
    struct Pairs *pair;
    pair = malloc(sizeof(struct Pairs));

    cmp_thread = malloc(thread_cmp_count*sizeof(pthread_t));
    for(thread = 0;(thread < thread_cmp_count); thread++){
        for(t = thread+1; t < n; t++){
            (*pair).i = thread;
            (*pair).j = t;
            pthread_create(&cmp_thread[index++], NULL, Compare, (void*) pair);

        }
    }

    for(thread= 0;(thread<thread_cmp_count); thread++){
        pthread_join(cmp_thread[thread], NULL);
    }

    free(cmp_thread);
}
```

And function Compare

```
void* Compare(void* pair){
    struct Pairs *my_pair = (struct Pairs*)pair;
    printf("\nThread %ld, %ld", (*my_pair).i, (*my_pair).j);
    return NULL;
}
```

Number I am getting and it is also random.

```
Thread 0,2
Thread 1,2
Thread 2,3
Thread 2,3
Thread 2,3
Thread 2,3
```

am i passing the `struct` wrong ?

Comment: Please note that in C, struct accesses through a pointer are never written as `(*foo).bar`: instead use `foo->bar`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That is because you are passing the same pointer to all pthreads.

When you invoke `pthread_create(..., (void*) pair)` you are passing the pointer to the new thread, but in the next iteration you are overwriting that memory (potentially before the new thread has extracted those values).

```
    long thread_cmp_count = (long)n*(n-1)/2;
    long t,index = 0;
    struct Pairs *pair;

    cmp_thread = malloc(thread_cmp_count*sizeof(pthread_t));
    for(thread = 0;(thread < thread_cmp_count); thread++){
        for(t = thread+1; t < n; t++){
            // allocate a separate pair for each thread
            pair = malloc(sizeof(struct Pairs));
            (*pair).i = thread;
            (*pair).j = t;
            pthread_create(&cmp_thread[index++], NULL, Compare, (void*) pair);

        }
    }

    for(thread= 0;(thread<thread_cmp_count); thread++){
        pthread_join(cmp_thread[thread], NULL);
    }

    free(cmp_thread);
```

.

```
void* Compare(void* pair){
    struct Pairs *my_pair = (struct Pairs*)pair;
    printf("\nThread %ld, %ld", (*my_pair).i, (*my_pair).j);

    // free that memory after it has been used
    free (pair);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: you got the problem right but that doesn't solve it. i used a pointer as an array of struct to avoid the overlap. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Problem solved. Problem was with overlap. using pointer as an `array` of type `struct` Pairs it is solved

Here is the correct code

```
long thread_cmp_count = (long)n*(n-1)/2;
long t,index = 0;
Pair * pair;
pair = malloc(thread_cmp_count*sizeof(Pair));

free(thread_handles);

thread_handles = malloc(thread_cmp_count*sizeof(pthread_t));
for(thread = 0;(thread < n-1); thread++){
    for(t = thread+1; t < n; t++){
        (pair+index)->i = thread;
        (pair+index)->j = t;
        pthread_create(&thread_handles[index], NULL, Compare, (void*) (pair+index));
        index++;
    }
}
for(thread= 0;(thread<thread_cmp_count); thread++){
    pthread_join(thread_handles[thread], NULL);
}

free(thread_handles);
```

And the function Compare

```
void* Compare(void* pair){
    long t,i,j;
    Pair *my_pair = (Pair*)pair;
    i = my_pair->i;
    j = my_pair->j;
    printf("\n..................................................................");
        if((x_array[i] < x_array[j])&&(x_array[i] != x_array[j])){
            w_array[i] = 0;
            printf(
                "\nThread T(%ld,%ld)"
                " compares x[%ld] = %ld and x[%ld] = %ld,"
                " and writes 0 to w[%ld]", i, j,
                i,x_array[i],
                j,x_array[j],
                i);
        }
        else if((x_array[i] > x_array[j])&&(x_array[i] != x_array[j])){
            w_array[j] = 0;
            printf(
                "\nThread T(%ld,%ld)"
                " compares x[%ld] = %ld and x[%ld] = %ld,"
                " and writes 0 to w[%ld]", i, j,
                i,x_array[i],
                j,x_array[j],
                j);
        }
        else
            return NULL;
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: I attempted this same code but getting error *dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct Pairs’*