# Passing a stack in C while using Threads

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, pthreads, pass-by-reference

I am trying to make a C program to count the number of frequency of words in a document and to split the document up into N parts with each part being counted by a different thread. Everytime I run the program, I get back nonsensical data, but if I run it without the threads I get back the data that I expect.

Here is the **Struct** named **BinarySearchTree.h**

```
typedef struct {
    char *num; /*! The contents of the <tt>Item</tt>.<br>Type: <tt>int</tt>*/
    int count;
} Item; /*! \typedef Item
        * \struct A struct represent one item.
        */

typedef struct node {
    Item info; /*! A struct with a one <tt>int</tt> on it. */
    struct node * left; 
    struct node * right; 
} Tree; 

typedef struct passargs {
    char *File;
    Tree *t;
    int splitStart;
    int splitEnd;
    int i;
    int a;
    char words[512][512];
} pass;
```

Here is the **main code** named **BinarySearchTree.c*:

```
#include "BinarySearchTree.h"
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

// Code for integer based BST from: https://gist.github.com/ArnonEilat/4611213

Tree * add(Tree* nod, char *number) {

    if (nod == NULL) {
        printf("Thread number %ld\n", pthread_self());

        printf("\nMaking new node for %s\n", number);
        nod = (Tree*) malloc(sizeof (Tree));
        if (nod == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }
        nod->info.num = number;
        nod->info.count=1;      //Increment the value if the same word is found
        nod->left = NULL;
        nod->right = NULL;
        return nod;
    }

    if (strcmp(nod->info.num, number)==0) {
        printf("%s==%s ",nod->info.num,number);
        printf("\t%s:%d ",nod->info.num,nod->info.count);
//        ++nod->info.count;
        nod->info.count++;
        printf("->%d\n ",nod->info.count);
        return nod;
    }
    if (strcmp(nod->info.num, number)>0){
        printf("%s>%s ",nod->info.num,number);
        nod->left = add(nod->left, number);
    } else {
        printf("%s<=%s ",nod->info.num,number);

        nod->right = add(nod->right, number);
    }

    return nod;
}

void printInorder(Tree* nod) {
    if (nod == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    printInorder(nod->left);
    printf(" %s: %d ", nod->info.num, nod->info.count);
    printInorder(nod->right);
}

void freeTree(Tree *root) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    freeTree(root->left);
    freeTree(root->right);
    free(root);
}

int newLines(char* File){   //Count the number of new lines in the file. Split based on those not word count
    int newLines=0;
    char buffTemp[5120];

    FILE *fp1 = fopen(File, "r");
    while(1)
    {
        if(fgets(buffTemp, 512, fp1) ==NULL)
            break;
        else{
            newLines++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    return newLines;
}
//This function reads the file and adds each entry to the tree, or increments if same word is present
Tree* read(pass* info){

    const char *delims = " \n"; //Deliminate by newlines and spaces
    char *token;
    int splitCounter=0;
    FILE *fp = fopen(info->File, "r");
    char buff[512];

    int aT=info->a;             //Putting variables into local ones
    int iT=info->i;
    int splitEnd = info->splitEnd;
    int splitStart = info->splitStart;
    char words[512][512];
    memcpy(words, info->words, 512);

    Tree* nod=info->t;

    while(1 && splitCounter<splitEnd)   //While the file does not end and we have not reached the end of the split
    {
        fgets(buff, 512, fp);
        splitCounter++;
        if(buff == NULL)
            break;
        else if (splitCounter>splitStart){
            printf("\t %s\n", buff);
            token = strtok(buff, delims);   //Split via the tokens and put them into buff
            while (token!=0) {
                strcpy(words[iT], token);
                iT += 1;
                token = strtok(NULL, delims);
            }
        }
    }

    for (;aT<iT;aT++){
        nod=add(nod, (char *)words[aT]);    //Add each word to the tree
    }
    printf("\n");
    fclose(fp);

    info->t=nod;
    memcpy(info->words,words,512);
    info->i=iT;
    info->a=aT;

    return nod;

}

int main() {
    Tree* t = NULL;
    pass args;
    args.t=t;
    args.i=0;
    args.a=0;
    args.splitStart=0;  //These splits are used to tell each thread where to look in the file
    args.splitEnd=0;
    args.File="/home/dib/CLionProjects/deleteme/readFile"; //Address of the file to be read

    int numLines=newLines(args.File);
    printf("\nnewLines %d\n",numLines);

    int split;
    printf("How many splits/threads would you like to create?\n");
    scanf("%d", &split);
    int iterator=numLines/split;
    printf("iterator %d:", iterator);
    const int NUMTHREADS= numLines/iterator + (numLines % iterator != 0);

    unsigned int p;

//    This for loop shows how I hope the threads would work. Uncomment the below block to see it work
    for (p=0; p<NUMTHREADS; p++){
        args.splitStart=args.splitEnd;
        if (args.splitEnd+iterator>numLines) args.splitEnd=numLines;
        else args.splitEnd+=iterator;
        read(&args);
    }

    pthread_t th[NUMTHREADS];
    int threads[NUMTHREADS];

    //This is my attempt at using threads to solve the same problem as the above for loop
//    for(p=0; p< NUMTHREADS; p++){
//        threads[p] = p;
//        args.splitStart=args.splitEnd;
//        if (args.splitEnd+iterator>numLines) args.splitEnd=numLines;
//        else args.splitEnd+=iterator;
//        printf("split end: %d",args.splitEnd);
//        pthread_create(&th[p], NULL, &read, &args);
//    }

    printInorder(args.t);

    freeTree(args.t);
    exit(0);
}
```

And finally the document I have been using as a test case named **readFile**:

```
five five five one two
two three three four four 
three six seven six six 
four six five seven seven
seven seven seven seven six
five four six
```

I tried implementing the solution found here : [passing struct to pthread as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196121/passing-struct-to-pthread-as-an-argument) 
but did not know what thread_handles was, and could not get it to work though the problem faced in that link is similar. So am I also just having a problem with memory allocation or is it something completely different?

Comment: A text file with mixed-length lines is hard to split up evenly.

Comment: As for your problem, you pass *the same pointer to all threads!* That means two or more threads could use the same data. What's more, each thread have it's own tree it modifies, and there's no attempt to combine each small per-thread tree into a large tree. Furthermore, there's no protection of shared data in the thread, leading to data-races. I suggest you find some beginners tutorials and books about threads and start learning from the beginning.

Comment: That is true, the way that I have it done currently is to count the number of newlines, and then split accordingly. So if the user had stated to have 3 threads, and there were 21 new lines, each thread gets 7 new lines to go through. Of course, this does decrease the efficiency as I go through the file twice.

Comment: @some programmer dude, do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Pass a different structure to each thread so that they each get their own data to work on?