# How can I pass a struct as an argument in a pthread function in C?

Tags: c, function, struct, arguments, pthreads

```
struct request 
{
    int  id;
    int  size;
    int  timestamp;
};
for(lots_of_threads = 0; lots_of_threads < threads; lots_of_threads++)
        {
         res = pthread_create(&(a_thread[lots_of_threads]),NULL, (void*)thread_function,&nums);
         if (res == 0) 
         {
          printf("\nPicked up a thread\n");
         }
         else
         {
          perror("pthread_join failed");
         }
         if (res != 0) 
         {
          perror("Thread creation failed");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
         }

         sleep (1);
         i=i+2;
        } 
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);  
        printf("Waiting for threads to finish...\n");
        //printf("All done\n");
        

        for(lots_of_threads = threads - 1; lots_of_threads >= 0; lots_of_threads--) {
            res = pthread_join(a_thread[lots_of_threads], &thread_result);
            if (res == 0) {
                printf("Picked up a thread\n");
            }
            else {
                perror("pthread_join failed");
            }
        }
        printf("\nAll done\n");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

This is what  I have written so far, but I want to pass the struct as an argument in the function.
So how can I pass my struct in the thread function, as a fifth argument, if that is possible?
The whole code compiles well though in my program within the main function. Also the "nums" argument is an array with integers of sizes, that I need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [passing struct to pthread as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196121/passing-struct-to-pthread-as-an-argument)

Comment: Not at all, because I already have four arguments.

Comment: The pthread_create() routine permits the programmer to pass one argument to the thread start routine. For cases where multiple arguments must be passed, this limitation is easily overcome by creating a structure which contains all of the arguments, and then passing a pointer to that structure in the pthread_create() routine.

Comment: How can I do that in my code, in order for my thread function to check if there is available an id from the request struct?

Comment: I'm not sure If I understand you correctly, but you can create new struct, which will have both `struct request` and `nums` argument inside it.
Then, in `thread_function` you can unpack them.
[this link](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#PassingArguments) might be helpful.

Comment: Note that you are running your threads serially, not concurrently.  You should have one loop to create the threads and a second loop to join them.  Otherwise, you might as well not use threading at all.  That's unrelated to how to pass structures to the thread function, but is generally relevant to how you use threads.

Comment: What you show is not compilable code.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  You save both the result of `pthread_create()` and `pthread_join()` in a single variable, `res`.  You then analyze `res` first as if it is the result of `pthread_join()` and then as if it is the result of `pthread_create()` — but by the time you're doing the second test, `res` is no longer the result of `pthread_create()`.

Comment: Just added a second for-loop for the pthread join function, thanks!

Comment: Also, does the void thread function need to have only the argument: (void*) args or can I pass as an argument my array (nums)? Will it create any problems with the use of this function later?

Comment: The thread function must accept exactly one argument, a `void *`.  The function must also return type `void *`, though it's fine for the actual return value to be null if you haven't anything meaningful to return.